# Mysql Request with 2 inner joins and inclusive select optimisation

Tags: mysql, optimization, bigdata, query-optimization, inner-join

I have this MySQL request that I run every two minuts, and I do that 4 times in parralel, meaning that every two minuts this request gets executed 4 times ( with different values in parameters), and after some time, my database gets overloaded, I've tried to do a bunch of updates to optimize it the more I can but my SQL knowledge arrives at its end so I refer to you, what could I do to optimize this request ?

```
SELECT bill.* FROM billing bill
   INNER JOIN subscriber s ON (s.subscriber_id = bill.subscriber_id)  
   INNER JOIN subscription sub ON(s.subscriber_id = sub.subscriber_id)          
   WHERE s.status = 'C' 
   AND bill.subscription_id = sub.subscription_id                       
   AND sub.package_name = 598
   AND sub.renewable = 1
   AND bill.billing_value IN ('not_ok BILLTOBE','not_ok BILL010 2','not_ok BILL010','not_ok BILL010 3')             
   AND sub.store = 'MTargetStore'
   AND (
     SELECT bill2.billing_date
     FROM billing bill2
     WHERE bill2.subscriber_id = bill.subscriber_id
     AND bill2.subscription_id = bill.subscription_id 
     AND bill2.billing_value NOT IN('not_ok BILL010','not_ok BILL010 2','not_ok BILL010 3')
     ORDER BY bill2.billing_date DESC LIMIT 1
   ) = bill.billing_date LIMIT 300
```

Show create table for subscription subscriber and billing (without unnecessary parameters)

Subscription

```
CREATE TABLE `subscription` (
      `subscription_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `subscriber_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `renewable` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
      `store` varchar(127) DEFAULT 'GooglePlay',

   `package_name` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`subscription_id`),
KEY `subscription_subscriber_id_subscriber_subscriber_id_idx` (`subscriber_id`),
KEY `renewableindex` (`renewable`),
KEY `subscription_index1` (`renewable`,`subscriber_id`,`subscription_id`),
KEY `subscription_index2` (`renewable`,`subscription_id`,`subscriber_id`),
CONSTRAINT `subscription_subscriber_id_subscriber_subscriber_id`
      FOREIGN KEY (`subscriber_id`)
      REFERENCES `subscriber` (`subscriber_id`)
      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2282403 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Subscriber

```
CREATE TABLE `subscriber` (
   `udid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `subscriber_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `status` varchar(3) DEFAULT 'CE',
   `consumer_id` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`subscriber_id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `udid_UNIQUE` (`udid`),
   UNIQUE KEY `subscriber_os_email_key` (`email`,`os`),
   UNIQUE KEY `consumer_id_UNIQUE` (`consumer_id`),
   KEY `sub_id_status` (`status`,`subscriber_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3655055 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Billing

```
CREATE TABLE `billing` (
   `billing_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `billing_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   `subscriber_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `billing_value` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
   `subscription_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`billing_id`),
   KEY `billing_subscriber_id_subscriber_subscriber_id_idx` (`subscriber_id`),
   KEY `subscriptionid` (`subscription_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `billing_subscriber_id_subscriber_subscriber_id`
         FOREIGN KEY (`subscriber_id`) REFERENCES `subscriber` (`subscriber_id`)
         ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9013743 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And finally the explain of the initial request:

```
1   PRIMARY sub ref PRIMARY,subscription_subscriber_id_subscriber_subscriber_id_idx,renewableindex,subscription_index1,subscription_index2  renewableindex  2   const   171836  Using where
1   PRIMARY s   eq_ref  PRIMARY,sub_id_status   PRIMARY 4   Infinitgame.sub.subscriber_id   1   Using where
1   PRIMARY bill    ref billing_subscriber_id_subscriber_subscriber_id_idx,subscriptionid   billing_subscriber_id_subscriber_subscriber_id_idx  4   Infinitgame.sub.subscriber_id   14  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  bill2   ref billing_subscriber_id_subscriber_subscriber_id_idx,subscriptionid   billing_subscriber_id_subscriber_subscriber_id_idx  4   Infinitgame.bill.subscriber_id  14  Using where; Using filesort
```

(or)

```
1   PRIMARY sub  ref             --  renewableindex  2  const                       171836  Using where
1   PRIMARY s    eq_ref          --  PRIMARY         4  Infinitgame.sub.subscriber_id    1  Using where
1   PRIMARY bill ref             --  bsss            4  Infinitgame.sub.subscriber_id   14  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY bill2 ref --  bsss            4  Infinitgame.bill.subscriber_id  14  Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical to performance.)  Before you ask about SQL performance read basics about it & the manual sections re 'index' & 'optimization'.

Comment: you should al least provide  your table schema with indexes  you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
        SELECT  bill2.billing_date
            FROM  billing bill2
            WHERE ...
            ORDER BY  bill2.billing_date DESC
            LIMIT  1
```

Say

```
        SELECT  MAX(bill2.billing_date)
            FROM  billing bill2
            WHERE ...
```

Do you really need 300 rows?  I suspect that is leading to 300 evaluations of that subquery.

```
    INNER JOIN subscriber s    ON (s.subscriber_id = bill.subscriber_id)  
    INNER JOIN subscription sub ON(s.subscriber_id =  sub.subscriber_id)          
    WHERE  s.status = 'C'
      AND  bill.subscription_id IN ( ... )
      AND  bill.subscription_id = sub.subscription_id
      AND  sub.package_name = 598
      AND  sub.renewable = 1
      AND  sub.store = 'MTargetStore'
```

Have these indexes (it is not clear which will be most useful):

```
s:  INDEX(status, subscriber_id)    -- (indexing flags is rarely useful)
bill:  INDEX(subscription_id)
sub:  INDEX(package_name, store, renewable, subscriber_id, subscription_id)
sub:  INDEX(package_name, store, renewable, subscription_id, subscriber_id)
```

The two indexes for `sub` -- depends on which order the Optimizer decides to access the tables.

```
AND  bill.subscription_id = sub.subscription_id
```

Shouldn't that be part of an `ON`?  It seems to define the relation.

A `LIMIT` without and `ORDER BY` -- You will get an unpredictable set of rows; is that OK?

To discuss this further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Also, what is the value of

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT subscriber_id, subscription_id)
     FROM  billing
     WHERE billing_value NOT IN('not_ok BILL010','not_ok BILL010 2',
                                'not_ok BILL010 3')
```

The answer may lead to a different way to do the subquery.

Also, would this work just as well in place of that `NOT IN`?

```
     WHERE billing_value NOT LIKE 'not_ok BILL010%'
```

When comparing a string (or `TEXT`) to a numeric string, quote the string:

```
  AND sub.package_name = "598"
```

Without the quotes, the index using `package_name` cannot be used effectively.

Comment: Huge shout out for your answer you are helping a lot

- Updated the max, gained about 20% of execution speed

- Also aded the indexes but I don't know how to verify if usefull or not, I used Explain but it seems the number of rows parsed is the same

- subscription_id is not the foreign key, I had to add the column on the billing table after I took back the database because it was only connected to subscriber and that was not practical

- Regarding the LIMIT it seems I always get 300 rows or less so it seems to be OK for me but maybe something I miss ?

Comment: Regarding last point you are also right, I was not sure if "NOT LIKE" was good in terms of performance ! 

Also 

-For the 300 rows, I have around 50k rows that I need to parse and then I need to call a server for each request, and the server takes 1 to 3 sec to answer, so it takes maximum 15min for the task to complete after what everything is saved in DB and depending on the result I need to do some other things.

> Updating my original post with the show create table and explain select

Comment: @AndRowID - I found why the index did not work for you -- quote the package name.  (See edit to my Answer.)